# Print item from interactive debugger in Ansible

Tags: debugging, ansible

I want to debug the content of the `item`s object in the following script interactively.

```yaml
- name: Deploy the apps from the apps directory to the splunk servers
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: '{{ absolute_file_store_path }}/etc/{{ selected_apps_sourcedir }}/{{ item.source_app }}/'
    dest: '{{ splunk_path }}/etc/apps/{{ item.name }}/'
    copy_links: true
    recursive: true
    checksum: true
    times: false
    delete: true
    owner: false
    group: false
    archive: false
    use_ssh_args: "{{ synchronize_module_use_ssh_args | default(false) }}"
    rsync_path: 'sudo -u {{ splunk_user }} rsync'
    rsync_opts: '{{ selectable_apps_rsync_opts + item.rsync_opts if item.rsync_opts is defined else selectable_apps_rsync_opts }}'
  notify: notify standalone splunkd restart
  loop: '{{ selected_apps | default([]) if selected_apps | default([]) is iterable else [] }}'
  when:
    - item.state == 'present'
    - item.dest_dir is not defined or
      item.dest_dir == "etc"
    - item.target is defined and item.target == inventory_hostname or
      item.target is not defined
```

For this I have checked [Enabling the debugger with the `debugger` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#enabling-the-debugger-with-the-debugger-keyword) but I cannot find any way to print `item` and it’s properties.

I have already added `debugger: always` and it stops there. The problem is that I don’t know the syntax to use to print `item` as it’s not in `task.args` or `task_vars`.

Is this even possible interactively? Means not with `msg` of the `debug` module?

Comment: "_I want to debug the content of the items object in the following script interactively._", can you provide more details regarding this? How that should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to debug interactively?**

> *I want to debug the content of the `items` object in the following script interactively. I have already added `debugger: always` and it stops there.*

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: [1, 2, 3]
    debugger: always
```

behaves like that.

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 3
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> p task.args
{u'msg': u'{{ item }}'}
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> task_vars['msg'] = 4
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> p task_vars['msg']
4
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> c

PLAY RECAP ********************************************
localhost                  : ok=1
```

As one can see [Enabling the debugger with the `debugger` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_debugger.html#enabling-the-debugger-with-the-debugger-keyword) happens after the loop surrounding the task has already finished.

> *The problem is that I don’t know the syntax to use to print `item` as it’s not in `task.args` or `task_vars`.*

Even if using correct syntax as in the documentation

```yaml
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> p task.args
{u'msg': u'{{ item }}'}
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> task_vars['msg'] = 4
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> p task_vars['msg']
4
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> c
```

it will not have an effect at that stage anymore.

> *I cannot find any way to print `item` and it’s properties.*

To print all task variables just use `p task_vars` within the interactive debugger, however, what you are looking for specifically will not be here in this example.

```json
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> p task_vars
{'ansible_check_mode': False,
 'ansible_config_file': u'/home/ansibe_user/test/ansible.cfg',
 'ansible_connection': 'local',
 'ansible_current_hosts': [u'localhost'],
 'ansible_dependent_role_names': [],
 'ansible_diff_mode': False,
 'ansible_facts': {},
 'ansible_failed_hosts': [],
 'ansible_forks': 5,
 'ansible_inventory_sources': (u'/home/ansible_user/test/inventory.ini',),
 'ansible_play_batch': [u'localhost'],
 'ansible_play_hosts': [u'localhost'],
 'ansible_play_hosts_all': [u'localhost'],
 'ansible_play_name': u'localhost',
 'ansible_play_role_names': [],
 'ansible_playbook_python': '/usr/bin/python2',
 'ansible_python_interpreter': '/usr/bin/python2',
 'ansible_role_names': [],
 'ansible_run_tags': (u'all',),
 'ansible_skip_tags': (),
 'ansible_verbosity': 0,
 'ansible_version': {'full': '2.11.12',
                     'major': 2,
                     'minor': 11,
                     'revision': 12,
                     'string': '2.11.12'},
 'environment': [],
 'group_names': [],
 'groups': {'all': [], 'ungrouped': []},
 'hostvars': {},
 'inventory_hostname': u'localhost',
 'inventory_hostname_short': u'localhost',
 'omit': '__omit_place_holder__1234567890',
 'play_hosts': [u'localhost'],
 'playbook_dir': u'/home/ansible_user/test',
 'role_names': [],
 u'software': AnsibleMapping([(u'all', AnsibleMapping([(u'name', u'All')]))]),
 'vars': {'ansible_check_mode': False,
          'ansible_config_file': u'/home/ansible_user/test/ansible.cfg',
          'ansible_connection': 'local',
          'ansible_dependent_role_names': [],
          'ansible_diff_mode': False,
          'ansible_facts': {},
          'ansible_forks': 5,
          'ansible_inventory_sources': (u'/home/ansibe_user/test/inventory.ini',),
          'ansible_play_batch': [u'localhost'],
          'ansible_play_hosts': [u'localhost'],
          'ansible_play_hosts_all': [u'localhost'],
          'ansible_play_name': u'localhost',
          'ansible_play_role_names': [],
          'ansible_playbook_python': '/usr/bin/python2',
          'ansible_python_interpreter': '/usr/bin/python2',
          'ansible_role_names': [],
          'ansible_run_tags': (u'all',),
          'ansible_skip_tags': (),
          'ansible_verbosity': 0,
          'ansible_version': {'full': '2.11.12',
                              'major': 2,
                              'minor': 11,
                              'revision': 12,
                              'string': '2.11.12'},
          'environment': [],
          'group_names': [],
          'groups': {'all': [], 'ungrouped': []},
          'hostvars': {},
          'inventory_hostname': u'localhost',
          'inventory_hostname_short': u'localhost',
          'omit': '__omit_place_holder__1234567890',
          'play_hosts': [u'localhost'],
          'playbook_dir': u'/home/ansible_user/test',
          'role_names': [],
          u'software': AnsibleMapping([(u'all', AnsibleMapping([(u'name', u'All')]))])}}
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)>
```

---

**Summary**

> *Is this even possible interactively?*

Not fully in the way requested. What you can do is

- Redefine the variable `item` via `task_vars['item'] = 0`
- `update_task`
- `redo` the run

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 3
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> task_vars['item'] = 0
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> update_task
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)> redo
[WARNING]: The loop variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to
avoid variable collisions and unexpected behavior.
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: 0
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: 0
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: 0
[localhost] TASK: debug (debug)>
```

Please take note the WARNING message about [Defining variable names with `loop_var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var).

---

**How to proceed further?**

> *I want to debug the content of the `items` object ...*

Such might also simply be possible by [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)

```yaml
  loop_control:
    label: " {{ item.state }}, {{ item.dest_dir }}, {{ item.target }}"
    pause: 1
```

and depending on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This ansible playbook library is quite huge and there are tons of tasks that either skip depending on various conditions or just don’t do anything because of missing content in the inventory file. In many cases it’s very hard to follow the current states over multiple tasks in multiple files. I was hoping that I could pause in loops and just have a look at the actual data of each item. Seems like I’ll just have to change my workflow and use loop_control though

Comment: Thanks for providing more information. "_I was hoping that I could pause in loops and just have a look at the actual data of each item._", that would be a nice feature but that's not how the debugger was implemented for, as well it is also not so easy to implement such functionality. "_have to change my workflow and use loop_control though_", right, that it was made for and will provide more control about the loop output ...