# How to create a new attribute using items from a list and append it back to the same list of dictionaries?

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, ansible-facts

I have this list:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ClassType": "Part Time",
      "FirstName": "Monice",
      "LastName": "Lee"
    },
    {
      "ClassType": "Full Time",
      "FirstName": "Henry Daley",
      "LastName": "Brown"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I create a new attribute `FullName`, which value would be `FirstName + ' ' + LastName` and append this to all the dictionaries of the list?

Expected output:

```json
{
 "data": [
    {
        "ClassType": "Part Time",
        "FirstName": "Monice",
        "LastName": "Lee",
        "FullName": "Monice Lee"
    },
    {
        "ClassType": "Full Time",
        "FirstName": "Henry Daley",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "FullName": "Henry Daley Brown"
    }
 ]
}
```

I tried this approach:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    FullName: "{{ item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName }}"
  loop: "{{ data }}"
```

However, the new variable ended up appearing under `ansible_facts.FullName` and not `item.FullName`.

**Output**

```json
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': 'Henry Daley', 'LastName': 'Brown', 'ClassType': 'Full Time'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "FullName": "Henry Daley Brown"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ClassType": "Full Time",
        "FirstName": "Henry Daley",
        "LastName": "Brown"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'FirstName': 'Monice', 'LastName': 'Lee', 'ClassType': 'Part Time'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "FullName": "Monice Lee"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "ClassType": "Part Time",
        "FirstName": "Monice",
        "LastName": "Lee"
    }
}
```

How can I create/append this `FullName` attribute each dictionary of the list?

Comment: Can you provide much much more details, information and description of what you try to achieve really? Currently it looks like a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576) for me.

Comment: Hi, I have already updated my question. I want to create a new variable, 'FullName', for each user in the list using their FirstName and LastName. It will be in this format: "FullName": "{{ FirstName + ' ' + LastName }}"

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`join`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) function of JMESPath to update your dictionary.

Given the task:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    data: >-
      {{
        data | json_query("
        [].{
          ClassType: ClassType,
          FirstName: FirstName,
          LastName: LastName,
          FullName: join(' ', [FirstName, LastName])}
        ")
      }}
  vars:
    data:
      - ClassType: Full Time
        FirstName: Henry Daley
        LastName: Brown
      - ClassType: Part Time
        FirstName: Monice
        LastName: Lee
```

Your `data` variable would be updated according to your need:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    data:
    - ClassType: Full Time
      FirstName: Henry Daley
      FullName: Henry Daley Brown
      LastName: Brown
    - ClassType: Part Time
      FirstName: Monice
      FullName: Monice Lee
      LastName: Lee
```

*<sup>Note: the above output was generated running the playbook with the option `-v`, which, amongst other useful information, shows the result of a `set_fact` task.</sup>*

Answer (score 2):

Create list *update*

```yaml
  update: "{{ data|json_query('[].[FirstName, LastName]')|
                   map('join', ' ')|
                   map('community.general.dict_kv','FullName') }}"
```

---

Optionally, the query below gives the same result

```yaml
  fn_query: "[].{FullName: join(' ', [FirstName, LastName])}"
  update: "{{ data|json_query(fn_query) }}"
```

---

gives

```yaml
  update:
  - FullName: Monice Lee
  - FullName: Henry Daley Brown
```

Update *data*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ data|zip(update)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  data:
  - ClassType: Part Time
    FirstName: Monice
    FullName: Monice Lee
    LastName: Lee
  - ClassType: Full Time
    FirstName: Henry Daley
    FullName: Henry Daley Brown
    LastName: Brown
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data:
    - ClassType: Part Time
      FirstName: Monice
      LastName: Lee
    - ClassType: Full Time
      FirstName: Henry Daley
      LastName: Brown

    update: "{{ data|json_query('[].[FirstName, LastName]')|
                     map('join', ' ')|
                     map('community.general.dict_kv','FullName') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: update
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ data|zip(update)|map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: data
```

Answer (score 1):

According your initial post

> *... it ended up appearing under `ansible_facts.FullName` and not `item.FullName` ...*

That's correct and the expected behavior.

> *How can I create/append this `FullName` variable to the list of `item` variables*

Short answer, you can't. At least not in that way and or without changing the Python code of `loop`. This is because the loop variables are not under the control of the task. One could think about of that that the loop code is surrounding the task code. The task code is not aware of that there is a loop outside.

If interested in more details or debugging you may have a look into [Print `item` from interactive debugger in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76173749/6771046).

The solution for your problem will be a more [complex data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) without a loop and is shown in the other answers here.